# Is this correlated subquery or non-correlated subquery?

Tags: sql

I am currently reading 'DATABASE SYSTEM CONCEPT' By *Abraham Silberschatz*, *Henry F. Korth* & *S. Sudarshan*.

In which there is an example of deletion, which is to delete the records of all instructors with salary below the average at the university.

They show the following query:

```
delete from instructor 
where salary < (select avg(salary) 
                from instructor);
```

I think the inner select query is non-correlated subquery! Means it should be executed only once and then outer select query.

But they provide the following explanation for the above SQL code snippet:

> The **delete** statement ﬁrst tests each tuple in the relation *instructor* to check whether the salary is less than the average salary of instructors in the university. Then, all tuples that fail the test—that is, represent an instructor with a lower-than-average salary—are deleted. Performing all the tests before performing any deletion is important—if some tuples are deleted before other tuples have been tested, the average salary may change, and the ﬁnal result of the **delete** would depend on the order in which the tuples were processed!

Above text suggest that the inner select query is a correlated subquery! Means for every row of outer relation it executes inner subquery.

I don't get it!

Can anybody tell me, is that **non-correlated** or a **correlated** subquery? Why?

Comment: It's a correlated subquery generally speaking, but in your example the result will be cached by the optimizer, because it has no row-dependent predicates propagating from the main query.

Answer (score 3):

In your current query, then subquery appearing in the `WHERE` clause is not correlated:

```
DELETE
FROM instructor 
WHERE salary < (SELECT AVG(salary) FROM instructor);
```

The SQL Server optimizer should evaluate the average subquery once, and cache that result to be used in the delete query.

However, consider the following version where the subquery *is* correlated:

```
DELETE
FROM instructor i1 
WHERE i1.salary < (SELECT AVG(i2.salary) FROM instructor i2
                   WHERE i2.department = i1.department);
```

This deletes all instructors whose salary happens to be less than the average for each department.  In this case, the subquery has a dependence on the table involved in the outer delete, and so this subquery is correlated.

Comment: Nice explanation